# Shutdown a vagrant box that is no longer configured

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I initially created a `Vagrantfile` that provisioned a default box. Later, I updated the `Vagrantfile` to use a named box ("db") with a slightly different config. Unfortunately, I forgot to halt the initial box before I provisioned the new box. Now there's a rogue vagrant box running in the background that I can't halt, even after rebooting the host machine.

```
$ vagrant global-status
id       name    provider   state    directory                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6b855b0  default virtualbox running  /Users/chrisbloom7/Projects/rails-upgrade 
d348c3b  db      virtualbox poweroff /Users/chrisbloom7/Projects/rails-upgrade 

$ vagrant halt -f 6b855b0
The machine with the name 'default' was not found configured for
this Vagrant environment.

$ cat Vagrantfile
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  config.vm.define "db", primary: true do |db|
    db.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.name = "rails-upgrade-development-mysql"
    end

    # ...
  end
end

$ git show HEAD^:Vagrantfile
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "box-cutter/ubuntu1004"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.name = "rails-upgrade-development"
  end

  # ...
end
```

I've checked in VirtualBox, but I don't see any boxes that are running. `ps aux | grep vagrant` and `ps aux | grep virtualbox` don't show anything either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out the `vagrant global-status` output was showing a red herring: It reads the status of all machines from `~/.vagrant.d/data/machines-index/index`. There really was no machine running as evident by the fact that no process were showing up using the `ps` command (H/T to @CEPA), and no machines appeared to be running in the VirtualBox application. That also explains why it's status was still "running" even after a reboot. Running `vagrant global-status --prune` cleaned up the file and thus the global status report.

Answer (score 2):

When I have a Vagrant box I can't communicate with, I kill the process.  The process name is usually `VBoxHeadless.exe` and will have the name in the full path where you can grep for it.  `ps aux | grep -i vbox | grep [put name here]`

Comment: I ran `ps aux | grep -i vbox ` but all I see is the grep process itself

Comment: I'm glad you found your own answer.

Comment: Thanks for the assist. Your answer led me to wonder why no processes were running.